# How do I access to my deleted questions?

Tags: bug, questions, deleted-questions

I created a question, submitted it, but after that I wanted to update it, but didn't have time so I deleted, to edit it later, but now I can't find it

How can I see my deleted questions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to search with the term `deleted:yes`. For [your posts specifically](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A40946+deleted%3Ayes), that would be:

```
user:40946 deleted:yes
```